# Disable button in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 buttons in my page "Save Set" & "Load Set".
"Save Set" button has ng-disabled=isSaveDisabled()

```
.....
.controller('saveLoadSetToolbarBtn', ['$scope','$modal','propertiesModified',
    function ($scope,$modal,propertiesModified) {
                  $scope.loadTuneSet = function () {

            $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'loadSetDlg.html',
                controller: 'loadSetCtrl'
            });
        };

        $scope.isSaveDisabled = function() {
            return !propertiesModified.get();
        };

.......
```

When I click Load Set, it will open a popup and their I'll have OK button. On this click, I should disable the "Save Set" button

OK Button,

```
.controller('loadSetCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'generalDataService',
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, generalDataService) {


        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.selectedSet = undefined;

        $scope.ok = function () {                
            //doing some logic
            closeDialog();
            $modalInstance.close();
        };
```

If any value changes happen in my page then this "Save Set" button will be enabled. problem is if I change any value in my page this button is enabling (as expected). If I click "Load Set" button, popup will open and on OK button click (available on Popup) then this "Save Set" should go back to Disable state. I should be able to return boolean value true through this isSaveDisabled function on OK button click.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How can I disable my "SaveSet" button on OK button click?

Comment: Can you please update your question to reflect that? What does your current code do, and what doesn't work? What is `propertiesModified`? Where is it updated?

Comment: If any value changes happen in my page then this "Save Set" button will be enabled. problem is if I change any value in my page this button is enabling (as expected). If I click "Load Set" button, popup will open and on OK button click (available on Popup) then this "Save Set" should go back to Disable state. I should be able to return boolean value true through this isSaveDisabled function on OK button click.

Comment: Can you please update your question with this information? The question doesn't contain all of the information required.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
<button ng-model="btnSaveSet" ng-disabled="btnSaveSet_disabled" 
ng-click="btnSaveSet_disabled=true">SaveSet</button>
```

Comment: what btnSaveSet_disabled is refer here?

Comment: a scope variable, give it any name

Comment: I already have a function isSaveDisabled() in controller "saveLoadSetToolbarBtn". Now I need to assign/override the boolean value of this function returning, from another one controller "loadSetCtrl"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to code a Modal View, like the Demo of this page : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ .

---

I recommend to try this demo and modify it to fit your needs, because there is not much to change. I try to give you some hints in the comments of the code: 

This is the JavaScript Code:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['tuneSet', 'tuneSet2','tuneSet3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'loadSetDlg.html',        // name it like the Template for the Modal
      controller: 'loadSetCtrl',    // name it like the used controller for the Modal
      size: size,                      // not necessary for you
      resolve: {
        items: function () {          // this will pass in your items into the ModalCtrl
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {      // here is the callback, when the
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;                        // Modal get closed
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());        
    });
  };
  
  // Here you can implement your logic depending on the user-input that is available on $scope.selected
  // it is an object. 
  
  console.log($scope.selected); // here you can see it in the console.
                                
  
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('loadSetCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]                // this will catch the user input (click on link)
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item); // this will pass the chosen tuneSet back to
  };                                            // ModalDemoCtrl

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});

And this is the HTML you need:
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="loadSetDlg.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">TuneSet selection!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!!! but this popup functions are fine already.... need to disable the button on OK button click.

Comment: then you can use ng-disabled="disable_SaveBtn" as an Attribute like   in Sameer's answer. The "disable_SaveBtn" should be a $scope - Variable that you can set true/false in your controller. Set it false in your callback of the Modal-View.